# Is it possible to get decision boundary equation for Quadratic Discriminant Analysis?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, quadratic, linear-discriminant

I use Python and sklearn packages.
I used LDA for predictions and I can get the coefficients of the decision boundary.

```
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(priors=[prob_norm, prob_anem]) 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = clf.predict(X_test)
print(clf.coef_[0][0], clf.coef_[0][1], clf.intercept_)
```

The same goes for QDA:

```
qda = QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis(store_covariance=True)
qda.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = qda.predict(X_test)
```

But there are no attributes to get decision boundary parameters.

However, there is a phrase for QDA:

> But it does not contain the coefficients of the linear discriminants, because the QDA classifier involves a quadratic, rather than a linear, function of the predictors.

It there any method to extract the parameters for the decision boundary for QDA?
I just don't understand the significant difference between linear and quadratic equations in this case.
Why it is possible to get linear but it's not for quadratic.